# Reach to HiDef XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, xna-3.0

I was converting one project from XNA 3.1 to XNA 4.0 and I was getting this error:

> Error 1   XNA Framework Reach profile does not support vertex shader
>   model 3.0.    J:\Utad\Mestrado\2Ano\Disserteção\Novos
>   softwares\xna\Codigo\VisualizadorXNA\VisualizadorXNA\VisualizadorXNAContent\BumpCylinder.fx   VisualizadorXNA

And after some research I found out that I had to change from Reach to HiDef in my project. After that the error desapeared but others have showed up. I have never seen this kind of error, and can't find a solution anywhere in the internet, the error was the following:

> Error 17  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime [c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   XNA\XNA Game
>   Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll]'
>   to
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime'    J:\Utad\Mestrado\2Ano\Disserteção\Novos
>   softwares\xna\Codigo\VisualizadorXNA\VisualizadorXNA\VisualizadorXNA\Game1.cs 208 35  VisualizadorXNA

This error is very weird. I could use some help in this one.

Best Regards,
Jorge

Comment: Hmm. Are all your projects using the same XNA version (4)? If you could post the code referenced by the error it would be a lot easier to help you troubleshoot it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd clear the solution, and would remove the "bin" and "obj" folders and every file with a suffix like "cache" or "user" in every project.

If it continues giving fails, I would remove the "Microsoft.Xna.Framework" references and I would add again to ensure are right.

Comment: it seems that you are mixing .dll references to xna 3.1 with .dll references to xna 4.0 in any of the projects inside the solution... are you sure that references are well?